# How to set parameter values to a "onClick" function using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set **parameters** to `onClick` event inside a html `button` using `javascript`.

This is how `html` button looks like:

```
<button type="button" id="upload-button" onclick="uploadFileIGCSE('param1', 'param2', 'param3')" class="btn btn-success" aria-expanded="false">Upload</button>
```

`param1` = should be the value from a `html select` element with `id='year'` and `name='year'`

`param2` = should be the value from a `html select` element with `id='grade'` and `name='grade'`

`param3` = should be the value from a `html select` element with `id='subject'` and `name='subject'`

These are the `html select options`

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <select id="year" name="year" class="form-control">
        <option value="select" disabled="disabled">- Select Year -</option>
        <option value="1">2001</option>
        <option value="2">2002</option>
        <option value="3">2003</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <select id="grade" name="grade" class="form-control">
        <option value="select" disabled="disabled">- Select Grade -</option>
        <option value="1">Grade 5</option>
        <option value="2">Grade 6</option>
        <option value="3">Grade 7</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <select id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control">
        <option value="select" disabled="disabled">- Select Subject -</option>
        <option value="1">Edexcel</option>
        <option value="2">National</option>
        <option value="3">Other</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I have no clue how to set values to `param1`, `param2`, `param3`

This is what I tried but it feels wrong.

```
$('#upload-button').val = $('#year').val;
```

Can someone please help me?

**I need to set values for the parameters (param1, param2, param3) in the function `uploadFileIGCSE('param1', 'param2', 'param3')` using `javascript` or `jquery`**

Thank you

Comment: You should wrap the function in a new anonymous function: `onclick="function(){ uploadFileIGCSE('param1', 'param2', 'param3'); }"` `fnName()` will call the function once and whatever that function returns will be bound as `onclick` handler.

Comment: I don't quite get what you are trying to say @LuudJacobs. Can you come up with an **example?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can understand your needs. if you really wanted to do this only with HTML element, here is the way.

```
<button type="button" id="upload-button" 
    onclick="uploadFileIGCSE(
             document.querySelector('#year').value, 
             document.querySelector('#grade').value, 
             document.querySelector('#subject').value)" 
    class="btn btn-success" aria-expanded="false">Upload</button>
```

Here is the working example

```js
function uploadFileIGCSE(val1, val2, val3){
  document.querySelector('#log').innerHTML = `${val1}, ${val2}, ${val3}`
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
    <select id="year" name="year" class="form-control">
        <option value="select" disabled="disabled">- Select Year -</option>
        <option value="1">2001</option>
        <option value="2">2002</option>
        <option value="3">2003</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <select id="grade" name="grade" class="form-control">
        <option value="select" disabled="disabled">- Select Grade -</option>
        <option value="1">Grade 5</option>
        <option value="2">Grade 6</option>
        <option value="3">Grade 7</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <select id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control">
        <option value="select" disabled="disabled">- Select Subject -</option>
        <option value="1">Edexcel</option>
        <option value="2">National</option>
        <option value="3">Other</option>
    </select>
</div>

<button type="button" id="upload-button" 
        onclick="uploadFileIGCSE(
                 document.querySelector('#year').value, 
                 document.querySelector('#grade').value, 
                 document.querySelector('#subject').value)" 
        class="btn btn-success" aria-expanded="false">Upload</button>
        
<p>log value : (<span id="log"></span>)</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't be using inline event listeners like `onclick` (for maintainability, security and separation of concerns reasons).

Instead, add the listener using the DOM API's `HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener()`:

```
document.getElementById('upload-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  uploadFileIGCSE(year.value, grade.value, subject.value);
})
```

```js
function uploadFileIGCSE(x,y,z) {
  console.log(x,y,z);
}

document.getElementById('upload-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  uploadFileIGCSE(year.value, grade.value, subject.value);
})
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
    <select id="year" name="year" class="form-control">
        <option value="select" disabled="disabled">- Select Year -</option>
        <option value="1">2001</option>
        <option value="2">2002</option>
        <option value="3">2003</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <select id="grade" name="grade" class="form-control">
        <option value="select" disabled="disabled">- Select Grade -</option>
        <option value="1">Grade 5</option>
        <option value="2">Grade 6</option>
        <option value="3">Grade 7</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <select id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control">
        <option value="select" disabled="disabled">- Select Subject -</option>
        <option value="1">Edexcel</option>
        <option value="2">National</option>
        <option value="3">Other</option>
    </select>
</div>

<button type="button" id="upload-button">Upload</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<button type="button" id="upload-button" onclick="getOption()" class="btn btn-success"
    aria-expanded="false">Upload</button>

function getOption() {
    var year = document.getElementById("year");
    var year_option = year.options[year.selectedIndex].value;

    var grade = document.getElementById("grade");
    var grade_option = grade.options[grade.selectedIndex].value;

    var subject = document.getElementById("subject");
    var subject_option = subject.options[subject.selectedIndex].value;

    uploadFileIGCSE(year_option, grade_option, subject_option)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The click event can simply run an anonymous function. Its only input will be the default `event` object supplied by the DOM engine. That function can then gather the values from the various elements you're interested in, and make a further call to the uploadFileIGCSE function, passing those values as parameters.

Here's a demo. Note that I've used an [unobtrusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) event handler using [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) in the JS code, rather than "onclick" within the HTML. This is generally considered to be better practice, as it makes the code easier to read, maintain and debug, and helps to separate the functionality from the presentation.

N.B. you could use jQuery for any/all of this, but equally it's not really necessary, it doesn't really add much value in this situation.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("upload-button");
button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  var year = document.getElementById("year").value;
  var grade = document.getElementById("grade").value;
  var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
  uploadFileIGCSE(year, grade, subject);
});

function uploadFileIGCSE(year, grade, subject) {
  console.log(year, grade, subject);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="upload-button" onclick="uploadFileIGCSE('param1', 'param2', 'param3')" class="btn btn-success" aria-expanded="false">Upload</button>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <select id="year" name="year" class="form-control">
    <option value="select" disabled="disabled">- Select Year -</option>
    <option value="1">2001</option>
    <option value="2">2002</option>
    <option value="3">2003</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <select id="grade" name="grade" class="form-control">
    <option value="select" disabled="disabled">- Select Grade -</option>
    <option value="1">Grade 5</option>
    <option value="2">Grade 6</option>
    <option value="3">Grade 7</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <select id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control">
    <option value="select" disabled="disabled">- Select Subject -</option>
    <option value="1">Edexcel</option>
    <option value="2">National</option>
    <option value="3">Other</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: No need for `event.preventDefault();` since `button[type=button]` has no default action.

Comment: @connexo very true. I hadn't clocked that. It's like a reflex action to add preventDefault lol. I'll remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#upload-button').click(function(e) {
    var year = $('#year').val();
    var grade = $('#grade').val();
    var subject = $('#subject').val();

    uploadFileIGCSE(year, grade, subject);
})
```

You could try something like this.